# node.js Internals: In a node.js addon, does String::New(long_c_static_string) creates a reference or a copy?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an node.js addon that should pass very long static strings to Javascript. 
Does String::New(static_string) makes a copy of the string or just passes the reference?

Answer (score 0):

It creates a copy. If you're creating a static string, you should just create it once and use that instead of creating it every time (if possible).